# error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CxxFrameHandler3

Tags: visual-studio, qt, qt5

I am migrating Qt to Qt 5.10.1 from VS 2013 to VS 2015. Getting following multiple link errors.

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CxxFrameHandler3
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol strcmp
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__invalid_parameter_noinfo_noreturn
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memcpy
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _CxxThrowException
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_calloc
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol fabs
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___stdio_common_vsprintf
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __std_terminate
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memset
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol strlen
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __C_specific_handler
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _initialize_narrow_environment
```

Note:In order to migrate to VS 2015, I have right clicked on project and upgraded to latest, in my case VS 2015

Answer (score 0):

In my project following link property was set to "Yes",

I have updated to "No" fixed my link error.

**Project->Properties->Linker->Input->IngoreAllDefaultLibraries to "NO"**

Comment: not working for me :/