# Error LNK2001: I have a simple Source.cpp and Graphs.h, and I get external symbol errors even though Source.cpp has `#include "Graphs.h"`?

Tags: c++, algorithm, linker-errors, prims-algorithm, lnk2001

I have a very basic Graphs algorithm program with a .cpp and a header. All necessary includes are there. I'm using Visual Studio 2019 16.7.1 Windows 10 2004 and Release x64 with multi-core turned on (Yes /Mp).
Am I missing something? Do I have to download/install anything? Change project properties? I'm fumbling in the dark here...

**Source.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include "Grafos.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //+++++Matriz-Lista Adyacencia+++++
    //+++++Prim+++++
    //Ejes de salida del nodo:<costo, nodo_adyacente>

    cout << "Main: " << endl;
    Grafos grafoCiudades;
    cout << "grafoCiudades: " << endl;
    Grafos::v_par_ints desdeSJ = { {5, 23}, {9, 45} };
    cout << "desdeSJ: " << endl;
    Grafos::v_par_ints desdeC = { {5, 12},{12, 45} };
    cout << "desdeC: " << endl;
    Grafos::v_par_ints desdeAlj = { {9, 12},{12, 23} };
    cout << "desdeAlj: " << endl;

    int cant_nodos = 3; //Nodos SJ (12), Cartago (23) y Alajuela (45)
    cout << "cant_nodos: " << endl;

    vector<Grafos::v_par_ints> grafoPRIM;
    cout << "grafoPRIM: " << endl;
    grafoPRIM.resize(cant_nodos);
    cout << "grafoPRIM.resize(cant_nodos): " << endl;

    grafoPRIM[0] = desdeSJ;
    cout << "grafoPRIM[0] = desdeSJ: " << endl;
    grafoPRIM[1] = desdeC;
    cout << "grafoPRIM[1] = desdeC: " << endl;
    grafoPRIM[2] = desdeAlj;
    cout << "grafoPRIM[2] = desdeAlj: " << endl;

    //Agrega nodos al AEM (raiz SJ)
    cout << "Costo del Prim AEM: " << grafoCiudades.Grafos::PrimAEM(0, grafoPRIM) << endl;
    cin.get();

    //+++++Kruskal+++++
    //+++++Dijkstra+++++
    //+++++Ptos. de Articulacion+++++

    return 0;
}
```

**Grafos.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class Eje {
public:
    int nodo_origen = 0;
    int nodo_final = 0;
    int costo = 0;
    Eje() {}
    Eje(int nodo_rev1, int nodo_rev2, int costo_eje) : nodo_origen(nodo_rev1), nodo_final(nodo_rev2), costo(costo_eje) {}
};

class Grafos {
public:
    typedef pair<int, int> par_ints;
    typedef vector<par_ints> v_par_ints;
    int cant_nodos = 0;
    vector <Eje> lista_ejes;
    vector <int> padre;
    vector <int> rango;

    Grafos() {}

    Grafos(int cant_nodos) {
        this->cant_nodos = cant_nodos;
        padre.resize(cant_nodos);
        rango.resize(cant_nodos);
    }

    int ListaAdyacencia();
    void AgregaEjes(Eje eje);
    int EncuentraPadre(int nodo);
    void KruskalAEM(vector<Eje>&);
    int PrimAEM(int nodoRaiz, vector<v_par_ints>& grafo);

    int Dijkstra();
    int PuntosArticulacion();
};

bool ComparaCosto(const Eje x, const Eje y) {
    return x.costo < y.costo;
}

int Grafos::ListaAdyacencia()
{
    return 0;
}

void Grafos::AgregaEjes(Eje eje) {
    lista_ejes.push_back(eje);
}

int Grafos::EncuentraPadre(int nodo) {
    if (padre[nodo] == nodo)
        return nodo;
    else
        EncuentraPadre(padre[nodo]);
}

void Grafos::KruskalAEM(vector<Eje>& result) {
    for (int i = 0; i < cant_nodos; i++) {
        padre[i] = i;
        rango[i] = 0;
    }
    sort(lista_ejes.begin(), lista_ejes.end(), ComparaCosto);

    for (auto& e : lista_ejes) {
        int raiz1 = EncuentraPadre(e.nodo_origen);
        int raiz2 = EncuentraPadre(e.nodo_final);

        if (raiz1 != raiz2) {
            result.push_back(e);
            if (rango[raiz1] < rango[raiz2]) {
                padre[raiz1] = raiz2;
                rango[raiz2]++;
            }
            else {
                padre[raiz2] = raiz1;
                rango[raiz1]++;
            }
        }
    }
}

int Grafos::PrimAEM(int nodoRaiz, vector<v_par_ints>& grafo)
{
    //priority_queue guarda el pair<peso, nodo>
    priority_queue<par_ints, vector<par_ints>, greater<par_ints>> q;
    //q es el nombre de toda esta variable std tipo queue

    //El costo de un nodo raiz al mismo es 0
    q.push(make_pair(0, nodoRaiz));

    //Codigo relativamente complicado de entender.
    //Determina el tamaño de memoria para alocar para el bool agregado
    //que determina si el nodo fue agregado o no al AEM
    bool* agregado = (bool*)::operator new(sizeof * agregado * grafo.size());
    //memset(agregado, false, sizeof(bool) * grafo.size());
    int costoAEM = 0;

    while (!q.empty()) {
        //Selecciona el par <costo, nodo> con el menor costo
        par_ints par;
        par = q.top();
        q.pop();

        int costo = par.first;
        int nodo = par.second;

        //Si el nodo es un nodo agregado al AEM entonces agregue
        //e incremente el costo.
        if (agregado != NULL) {
            if (!agregado[nodo]) {
                costoAEM += costo;
                agregado[nodo] = true;

                //Itera
                for (auto& par_costo_nodo : grafo[nodo]) {
                    int nodo_adyacente = par_costo_nodo.second;
                    if (agregado[nodo_adyacente] == false) {
                        q.push(par_costo_nodo);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ::operator delete(agregado);
    return costoAEM;
}

int Grafos::Dijkstra()
{
    return 0;
}

int Grafos::PuntosArticulacion()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1>Source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CxxFrameHandler4
1>Source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __std_exception_destroy
1>MSVCRT.lib(throw_bad_alloc.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __std_exception_destroy
1>Source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __std_exception_copy
1>MSVCRT.lib(throw_bad_alloc.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __std_exception_copy
1>Source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __std_terminate
1>Source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__invalid_parameter_noinfo_noreturn
1>MSVCRT.lib(new_scalar.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _callnewh
1>MSVCRT.lib(new_scalar.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol malloc
1>MSVCRT.lib(delete_scalar.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol free
1>MSVCRT.lib(throw_bad_alloc.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _CxxThrowException
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50327296/error-lnk2001-unresolved-external-symbol-cxxframehandler3 might be relevant

Comment: Have you just changed version of MSVC? The linker errors are not to do with your graphos code, but appears more to do with visual studio libs. Like its linking with older vs libs or something, for example `malloc` and `free` are part of the standard libs

Comment: @code_fodder yes, I updated from 16.7.0 to 16.7.1 yesterday. Might that be it?

Comment: @AlanBirtles I came across that answer as well. Tried it, didn't work :(
Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: @DanielPantigoso hmm... I would not expect a minor update to cause an issue - but I guess it might, I was thinking more along the lines of update from vs2017 -> vs2019. Was it compiling before the update?

Comment: A mix of runtime libraries would be my next guess, please provide a [mre]